# Number of connected components in an undirected graph

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove that the number of connected components in a undirected graph is at most $\frac{n}{2}$.

And is it true that an undirected graph doesn't have circuits?

Answer (score 1):

I think that both your statements are wrong.

1. If you denote by $n$ the number of vertices just take a look at a graph that consists of $3$ vertices and $1$ edge between two of them, so the other one is disjoint. That graph has $2$ connected components, but $\frac{3}{2} < 2$.
2. Imagine an ordinary triangle as an undirected graph with $3$ vertices and $3$ edges.

Maybe you should specify your question if I mentioned things that you didn't mean.

Comment: Actually I missed something. It's undirected connected graph, is there a difference and the statements become true?

Comment: When it's already known that the graph is connected than you are sure that it has only one connected component by definition and the first statement lose any sense at all. My second example is connected but the whole graph forms a circuit as you can see.